# Регулярное выражение для извлечения внутри определенного тега

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
<i>Текст</i>
    <u><img src="1.jpg"></u>
<i>Текст</i>

<i>Текст</i>
    <i><img src="2.jpg"></i>
<i>Текст</i>

<i>Текст</i>
    <i>
        <u>Текст</u>
        <img src="3.jpg">
        <u>Текст</u>
    </i>
<i>Текст</i>
```

Как выбрать `<img src="2.jpg">` и `<img src="3.jpg">`?
На ум пришло только это выражение `\<i[^<]*\<img.*?\<\/i\>`, но оно не включает последний вариант.

Comment: Достаточно `<img.*?\>`

Пример можно посмотреть тут:
https://regex101.com/r/CQ1Gv1/1

Или вам не нужен первый тег?

Comment: Да, не нужен первый случай =))

Answer (score 0):

Это выражение:

```
(?<!\<u\>)\<img[^>]+\>
```

выберет два блока:

```
<img src="2.jpg">
<img src="3.jpg">
```

Надеюсь я правильно понял задачу.